# Use jos_content id column in another table in Joomla database

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have created Joomla articles connected to the Joomla's default database, and I want to create new table where I would store the results from those pages (Articles are tests).

```
<?php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "INSERT INTO jos_results(id, question1) VALUES ((select id from jos_content), '$answers')"; 
$db->setQuery($query); 
$db->query();
?>
```

As you see above, I created a new table jos_results, and what I want is that in this table I have a column question1 where I would store text data from variable $answers. The other column would be the id. This id I tried to be the column from default jos_content.

jos_content stores articles in Joomla, and it has auto_increment column id. I want when users open some article, and fill in their questions there, there should be new row created which will have an id (actually the id from the article opened) and question1 column with their answers from post variable.

Mysql looks like this:

```
'jos_results' (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `question1` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

There is an error somewhere :( 
Subquery returns more than 1 row SQL=INSERT INTO jos_results(id, question1) VALUES ((select id from jos_content), 'there is my answere here blah blah...')

Comment: Thanks for asking a Joomla question. Did you know that we are getting really close to a dedicated Joomla site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla? Commit and help us get the beta site launched!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written you are asking for all the id's on the jos_content table. You should add a WHERE to the subquery to return only one value.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO jos_results(id, question1) VALUES ((select id from jos_content WHERE <your_condition>), '$answers')";
```

By the way, you should sanitize $answers before using this way.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Add a GROUP BY clause with a COUNT() in the SELECT clause to find your duplicates.